# Running an async function before express.js start

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, async-await

I want to run an async operation (for example, wait for a URL call to complete) before I start my app. I don't know how to do that (since it's an upper-level application - no async/await here).

www.js:

```
var app = require('./app');
var http = require('http');
const port = '3000';
app.set('port', port);
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
```

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var Promise = require('bluebird');

# HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO "AWAIT" AN ASYNCHRONOUS CALL. 
# I KNOW I CAN'T USE AWAIT BECAUSE I'M NOT WITHIN 
# AN "ASYNC" ANNOTATED FUNCTION. EXAMPLE:
const data = await Promise.promisify(fs.readFile('DATA'));

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', routes);
module.exports = app;
```

I thought about wrapping all of `app.js` with a Promise.promisify() so I can use async await withing it. But I'm not sure how that would be handled in `www.js`, since it is not invoked, as in `app()` but passed on to `http.createServer`

Comment: Have you looked up tutorials on promises?  Here's a good start: https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: *What* asynchronous call? Also, `app.js` doesn't show any exports, and yet you're using it as though it had.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you are right. My bad. Edited to add export and illustrate reading a file (I know there's a sync version. Let's assume there isn't or I'm using some other Promised call)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From what you've said, `app.js` is presumably exporting something (perhaps `app`?) but that something isn't ready to be used until an asynchronous call (which I don't think you've shown) is complete.

Assuming that's all true, then what `app.js` exports needs to provide a way for the things using it to wait until it's ready. One way to do that is to use a promise.

Assuming what you're waiting for isn't promise-ified, then:

`app.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
exports.appPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    startTheAsyncOperation(function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            reject(err);
            return;
        }
        app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
        app.set('view engine', 'jade');
        app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
        app.use('/', routes);
        resolve(app);
    });
});
```

then in `www.js`:

```
var appPromise = require('./app').appPromise;
var http = require('http');
const port = '3000';
appPromise.then(function(app) {
    app.set('port', port);
    var server = http.createServer(app);
    server.listen(port);
});
```

---

Of course, if the async thing you're waiting for provides a promise to you, you don't need `new Promise` in `app.js`; instead:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
exports.appPromise = startTheAsyncOperation().then(function() {
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use('/', routes);
    return app;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the async package. For your needs, you should go with the waterfall control flow provided by the async package. [You can have a look as it is very well documented.](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#waterfall)

You can wrap your code with the waterfall function and this part of your code will be running synchronously.

Edit: Updated Link, but the accepted answer has a better approach imho.

Comment: your url returns a 404