# What is the correct way to import a Promise?

Tags: typescript, express, promise, tslint

I'm trying to understand the concept of typescript imports especially of an exported Promise. I followed the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41364294/3969007 and it works. But the ts-lint rule 'no-var-requires' doesn't like this solution. Hence my question.

The code I currently use (min-example):

```
// app.ts
import Express from 'express';
import { createConnection } from 'typeorm';

const app = Express();
const main = async () => {
    await createConnection();
}

export const appPromise = main().then(() => app);
```

```
// server.ts
import http from 'http';
const appPromise = require('./app').appPromise;

const httpPort = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '8080');
let httpServer: any;
appPromise.then((app: Express.Application) => {
    httpServer = http.createServer(app);

    httpServer.listen(httpPort);
});
```

As I said, ts-lint doesn't like that import. So I tried to change it to:

```
import appPromise = require('./app').appPromise;
```

But in that case, it doesn't like the .appPromise part and later on then (appPromise.then) does not exist on type 'type of import'. I guess I did not understand something very essential regarding imports / exports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import { appPromise } from './app';
```